# Using sed to find and replace complex string

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a large file with strings like "xyz.abc.001.xxx.0.820" and I want to replace it with "0,820,xyz.abc.001.xxx" in total file.

Examples:

```
xyz.abc.001.xxx.0.820\ to 0,820,xyz.abc.001.xxx 
xyz.abc.001.xxx.820.123\ to 820,123,xyz.abc.001.xxx
xyz.abc.001.xxx.1000.2000\ to 1000,2000,xyz.abc.001.xxx 
xyz.abc.001.xxx.1.100\ to 1,100,xyz.abc.001.xxx
```

I am using below sed command with regular expression but not replacing correctly

```
sed -E "s/(xyz.abc[0-9]\+\.xxx)\.([0-9]\+)\.([0-9]\+)\\/\2,\3,\1/g" file_name
```

Is it possible do like this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your post is not entirely clear, e.g. you have `0:820` in your first output example, but comma-separation for the first two fields in the rest; is that a typo? Is it correct to say that you want to _prepend_ the strings with the last two `.`-separated fields, but comma-separated? What about the `\ `, is that really there? Does it need to be  `sed`, or is `awk` a valid alternative?

Comment: we all asume `:820` is a typo and should be `,820` (comma 820), is this right ?

Comment: @Archemar yes that's right, it should be ,820 (comma 820). I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try either

```
sed -E "s/(xyz.abc.*xxx).([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)./\2,\3,\1/" 
sed -E "s/(xyz.abc.*xxx).([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\\\\/\2,\3,\1/"
```

where

- pattern select is done by `\( ... \)`
- trailling `\` can be caught either by `.` (any char), or `\\\\` (escape from shell and escape from sed)
- note I use either `.` or `\.` to specify a dot

Answer (score 0):

Can't try it right now, but it doesn't look too wrong to me. `\+` is out of standard, so try

```
sed -E "s/(xyz\.abc[0-9]{1,}\.xxx)\.([0-9]{1,})\.([0-9]{1,})\\/\2:\3,\1/g" file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be `sed`, you can try the following `awk`-based solution:

```
awk -F. -v OFS="." '{sub(/\\$/,"",$NF); printf("%s,%s,",$NF,$(NF-1)); NF=NF-2}1' input.txt
```

This will interpret each line as `.`-separated fields, strip the trailing `\` from the last, and print the last two fields comma-sepated at the beginning of the output line, followed by remaining fields (again `.`-separated).